# .Net Winform Button as COM for FoxPro C00005 Error

Tags: .net, com, foxpro, visual-foxpro

we created a .net (3.5) COM control for foxpro (9 with SP), according to the guides you can find on the web (for example from rick strahls weblog)

now sometimes in foxpro we got a C000005 when releasing the object.

So we tried to reproduce this sceanrio. When instanticate and release the object hundred / thousend of times we got the same  error.

We use a emptry FoxPro SCX Form, and a simple .net button without any code.

If we don't dispose the .net object we got an similar .net exception "Attempted to read or write protected memory"

".(complete exception see at the bottom)

here the VFP Code:

```
Local lnAnzahl as Number, ;
 lni as Number

set procedure to DummyProcedure.prg

lnAnzahl = val(inputbox("wie oft", "oft","0"))

for lni = 1 to lnAnzahl
 thisform.newobject("cntTest","netcontrol","c0005nativetest.vcx")
 thisform.RemoveObject("cntTest")     
endfor
```

.net error message

> System.AccessViolationException: Es wurde versucht, im geschützten
>   Speicher zu lesen oder zu schreiben. Dies ist häufig ein Hinweis
>   darauf, dass anderer Speicher beschädigt ist.    bei
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IAdviseSink.OnViewChange(Int32
>   aspect, Int32 index)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ActiveXImpl.ViewChanged()    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ActiveXImpl.ViewChangedInternal()    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnInvalidated(InvalidateEventArgs e)
>   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.NotifyInvalidate(Rectangle
>   invalidatedArea)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invalidate(Boolean invalidateChildren)
>   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmUpdateUIState(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ActiveXImpl.System.Windows.Forms.IWindowTarget.OnMessage(Message&
>   m)    bei
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Is this an known problem?
any advice how we can solve it ?

Comment: Looks like you use an ActiveX control on your form.  Looks like it is buggy.  Contact the vendor or author of the control for support.

Comment: I would agree, probably a problem with the activeX control. If you created this control, try putting some logging into the control to see if you can capture the error or problem.

Comment: its the base .net button only made comvisible and set the appropriate attributes.

Comment: You mention Rick's blog.  Can you edit your question and paste a link to it for me to review.  I've built many a VFP COM control for web purposes in the past but don't know the contextual basis you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

We have had this error in a production environment.

Apparently it is impossible to truly release the .NET COM component from the VFP environment: it is held in memory until the application ceases.

Rick Strahl gives a very elegant solution to the problem we encountered here:

[Hosting the NET Runtime in Visual FoxPro](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Jul/01/Hosting-the-NET-Runtime-in-Visual-FoxPro)

...which links to other posts discussing the issues, summarised below:

> The .NET runtime locks into VFP:
>   Once you load a .NET COM component you can’t unload this component completely. This means during .NET COM development you have to shut down Visual FoxPro to reload a .NET COM component.
>
> .NET Components may not unload related resources:
>   The .NET Garbage Collector cleans up objects and object state inside of the .NET instance running. This means when you delete an object the actual object and it related resources may unload immediately. For example, if you load a Bitmap object which has associated memory buffers, and simply clear the reference, the associated memory buffer data does not release immediately. Using the Dispose() method, when available, can help here to explicitly unload related resources.
>
> Not all types work in Visual FoxPro:
>   Some data types – specifically value types and some specialized collection types – don’t work in Visual FoxPro when accessed over COM. Also some array types passed from COM to Visual FoxPro cannot be modified and sent back with new or removed elements.
>
> Passing types from FoxPro to .NET is usually not type safe:
>   Unless you have VFP COM components that you pass to .NET you cannot easily pass strongly typed objects created in Visual FoxPro to .NET. FoxPro objects pass as generic ‘object’ references and have to be accessed with Reflection in most cases.

Comment: After at lot of time of investigation and a lot of discussion with other developers and tests we found out that this problem is really unsolveable. We also added some Marshall.ReleaseCOMObject code which improved the behavior. but related to some .net and windows version the problem still raised. Imo as a summary the best solution ist to end to use FoxPro. As it isn't supported anymore, does not get any new bugfixes and is in the mean time a potential security risk.

Comment: "The best solution ist to end to use FoxPro" Agreed :) Doesn't always go down well in product development meetings though.